# Amazon DynamoDBMapper.delete method does not delete item

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I used AWS DynamoDBMapper Java class to build a repository class to support CRUD operations. In my unit test, I created an item, saved it to DB, loaded it and then deleted it. Then I did a query to DB with the primary key of deleted item, query returns an empty list, all looked correct. However, when I check the table on AWS console the deleted item is still there, and another client on a different session can still find this item. What did I do wrong? Is there any other configuration or set up required to ensure the "hard delete" happened as expected? My API looks like this:

```
public void deleteObject(Object obj) {
    Object objToDelete = load(obj);
    delete(obj);
}

public Object load(Object obj) {
    return MAPPER.load(Object.class, obj.getId(),
        ConsistentReads.CONSISTENT.config());
}

private void save(Object obj) {
    MAPPER.save(obj, SaveBehavior.CLOBBER.config());
}

private void delete(Object obj) {
    MAPPER.delete(obj);
}
```

Any help/hint/tip is munch appreciated

Comment: To make the whole issue more interesting(odd), I created a new test case, and the result is quite amazing. My first three test cases are testCreate, testUpdate and testDelete. After each operation I read back from DynamoDB to validate my operation as mentioned in the original post. Then the 4h test case is to Create->Fetch->Delete, all in one method. And in the fourth test case the item is created then deleted as expected. Don't know why put them all in one method makes such a big difference.

Comment: Dynamodb is eventually consistent. Creating -> Read -> Delete immediately would not always work.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamodb is **eventually consistent** by default.  Creating -> Reading -> Deleting immediately would not always work.

> Eventually Consistent Reads (Default) – the eventual consistency
>   option maximizes your read throughput. However, an eventually
>   consistent read might not reflect the results of a recently completed
>   write. Consistency across all copies of data is usually reached within
>   a second. Repeating a read after a short time should return the
>   updated data.
>
> Strongly Consistent Reads — in addition to eventual consistency,
>   Amazon DynamoDB also gives you the flexibility and control to request
>   a strongly consistent read if your application, or an element of your
>   application, requires it. A strongly consistent read returns a result
>   that reflects all writes that received a successful response prior to
>   the read.